# How to change chart js data on button click

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want to update the chart data through input fields. First time it draw the chart correctly but if i am trying to enter new data it is not updating the chart and still showing old data chart.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>chart</title>    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
            <input type="number" placeholder="" class="input-field" id="data1">
            <input type="number" placeholder="" class="input-field" id="data2">
            <button type="button" onclick="draw()" class="my_btn">submit</button>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
        
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="chart.js"></script
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code
How can i update the chart with new data.

```
function draw(){
var data1 = Number(document.getElementById("data1").value);
var data2 = Number(document.getElementById("data2").value);



var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "doughnut",
   data: {
       labels: ['data1', 'data2'],
        datasets: [{
            label:"Amount",
         data: [data1, data2],
         backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                
           ],
           borderColor: [
               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
    options: {
      scales: {
      
      
        }
  }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To update the chart, you will have to invoke update method of the chart as below:

```
myChart.update();
```

Comment: I try it but don't work i think it put it in wrong place. Can you tell me where i should write this code.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question as well on youtube but somehow it was suddenly gone. However I created the video covering complete details and you can also see the mistakes you made in your code and how I convert it into a working chart which updates on click. Watch full explanation here: https://youtu.be/YA4ZgurFWV0

```
    <div class="chartBox">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <input type="number" id="value1">
  <input type="number" id="value2">
  <button id="updateChart">Update</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
// setup block
const data1 = 55;
const data2 = 11;
const data = {
  labels: ['data1', 'data2'],
    datasets: [{ // index 0
      label: 'Amount',
      data: [data1, data2],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',  
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      cutout: '90%'
    }]

  };

// config block
const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
    scales: {}
  }
};

// render /init block      
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);

const value1 = document.getElementById('value1');
const value2 = document.getElementById('value2');
value1.value = data1;
value2.value = data2;

const updateChart = document.getElementById('updateChart');
updateChart.addEventListener('click', updateDoughnutChart);

function updateDoughnutChart(){
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = value1.value;
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data[1] = value2.value;
  myChart.update();
}

</script>
```